# Extend doesn't show effects in R package simr

Tags: r

I'm trying to reproduce the example of Green and MacLeod in https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12504.

```
library(simr)
model1 <- glmer(z ~ x + (1|g), family="poisson", data=simdata)
summary(model1)
fixef(model1)["x"] <- -0.05  # Specify desired effect size
model3 <- extend(model1, along="g", n=15) # Add more groups
summary(model3)
```

However, in the output of model 3, the number of groups is not extended (same result as in model 1):

```
Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 g      (Intercept) 0.08345  0.2889  
Number of obs: 30, groups:  g, 3
```

I know that by checking the rows I get different results, but why isn't that part of the regression? Am I doing something wrong? How can I extend the number of groups so that I can calculate a proper powerCurve?

```
> nrow(getData(model1)) 
[1] 30
> nrow(getData(model2)) 
[1] 130
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, well done on checking that the functions are doing what you expect. I hadn't expected users to be quite this thorough.

`model3` now has two datasets attached to it. The original one that lme4 knows about, and an attribute `newData` that simr checks instead.

So `print` and `summary`, which are part of lme4, give you values from the old dataset.

But `getData` and `powerSim` and `powerCurve` in simr will use the new extended dataset:

```
> powerSim(model3, nsim=10, progress=FALSE)
Power for predictor 'x', (95% confidence interval):
      80.00% (44.39, 97.48)

Test: z-test
      Effect size for x is -0.050

Based on 10 simulations, (0 warnings, 0 errors)
alpha = 0.05, nrow = 150

Time elapsed: 0 h 0 m 0 s
```

I've opened an issue on the github repository, this is probably a bug that should be fixed.